# Confused: Why to do i have to map my entity object to viewmodel object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

i am a complete newbie to the entity framework,mvc just started with it 3 weeks ago.
From then i have been beating around the bush searching for the right approach.the more i dig the more i get lost...i am afraid that i could not proceed any further with using entity framework in mvc

I m lost and frustrated :(

what i have been trying to do is to use entity framework for the MVC application.For that i have started with creating an School.edmx file(which has School.Designer.cs automatically created for it.I dont have any POCO or any others just plain edmx with designer class).Then through some searching i have found that its bad practice to use entity object as model for view.....

Now the real thing started i have made a viewmodel for an entity object.The thing is i dont really get why i have to use a repository and why do i have to map my entity objects and viewmodel objects.Everytime i search why i have to map i get some links saying how to use automapper and the more i search about repository the more i get lost .i dont even understand it.why do i have to map ...??? and why do i have to use repository.

And now the other thing i ask repeatedly to myself is why do i have to write data annotation again in the Viewmodel class when i have already data annotated it in my designer.cs file (like [Required],[Email] and other annotations)..? WHY to write them again!! (If i dont mention them in viewmodel i dont see the annotations working). Duplication of annotation...?

I am lost and i dont even know where i m now
someone give me the right path to follow
                                                                
 Yours Sincerely,
                                                              
 Lost & Confused Newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing is i dont really get why i have to use a repository

MVC helps you write code that has a clear separation of concerns. In this case, the repository is meant to how the application interacts with the data storage for a specific entity. If you want a `Student` entity you call `StudentRepository.GetEntity()`. If you want to save to save you call the `StudentRepository.SaveEntity(Student student)`.

> Why do i have to map my entity objects and viewmodel objects.Everytime i search why i have to map i get some links saying how to use automapper and the more i search about repository the more i get lost.

While you can use these entities directly in your view for simple cases, the problem comes up when you have more complex views - composite views that may need multiple entities, views that need to expose only a subset of an entity or even a subset of multiple entities. So yes, you can just expose your entity directly but I find it easier just to create a separate view model.

Automapper is used to help map from view model to entity. So, instead of writing a lot of

```
entity.Name = viewModel.Name;
entity.Age = viewModel.Age;
...
```

Automapper is used to automatically map these properties.

> And now the other thing i ask repeatedly to myself is why do i have to write data annotation again in the Viewmodel class when i have already data annotated it in my designer.cs file (like [Required],[Email] and other annotations)..?

You should specify validation logic specific for each view in the view model so that if validation fails at the controller it can stop processing instead of continuing. Even though mapping your view model to an entity and trying to save would be prevented by the entities data annotation, I find it clearer to look at a view and its view model to understand what's going on instead of going from view to view model to entity.

Update:

Take a look at [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx) and [How we do MVC – View models](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/). I found them both useful when trying to understand view models.

Comment: please give me a scenario where i need to map my viewmmodel with entity object..at the time of saving data i have to map?

Comment: Lets say you have a `Student` entity and a view `Edit`. When you submit the form you would be mapping from the `EditViewModel` to the `Student` entity and this would be done at the controller level on the action that handles the submit. I've also updated my answer with 2 useful links.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't Fret!**

Entity Framework is a big beast of a framework based on another beast of a framework: ADO.NET. It's very difficult to truly understand Entity Framework apart from understanding ADO.NET.

That being said, Entity Framework is the perfect tool in some scenarios. However, you (like many of us) seem to have a disconnect about the roles of EF, ASP.NET MVC, and a Repository.

The thing is, you *don't* need a repository. You don't even need a view model. You don't need EF. And you don't even need ASP.NET MVC. All of these tools are used to make specific jobs easier. None of them have direct ties to each other, and any of them can be used independently of each other.

**A Repository**: is used to *put* certain objects into some *persistent* place, so that you can *get* them later. That's really all it is.

**ASP.NET MVC**: Is an HTTP Handler that takes the requested URL and instantiates a *controller* class which in turn serves up *views*. The views display some *model*, and because the views are interactive, they allow the user to send yet another *request*, starting the whole thing over again. Because this process is (intentionally, but not necessarily) stateless, some sort of *persistence* is required. This persistence can be a file on the server, a file database, or in most cases a relational database.

**Entity Framework**: sits on top of ADO.NET (Microsoft's relational database abstraction framework), and allows you to *map* objects from a graphical (in memory) form to a relational (in-database) form, and back again. The ***idea*** is to allow the developer to *easily map* objects to and from the database. However, this is not a simple process, and because you're not directly interacting with the database (be it via ADO.NET or not), there is some inherent complexity. One of those complexities is the display of the information.

**View Models** (asp.net mvc view models): allow models to be displayed in various forms. For instance, we may have a "scholastic record" table, and a "person" table, and together they might form a "student". Because our entities are "ScholasticRecord" and "Person", we cannot (as) simply display the information on the view. For this reason, we create a *view model* to combine and display the information as a "Student".

View Models also prevents us from accidentally calling "lazy" methods on our entities while in the view, which might query the database. This isn't *bad*, but it could get confusing, because our *view* is doing *repository-like* work (which isn't very [S]OLID).

**TLDR;**

The reason you're having trouble is *probably* because you're trying to do everything at once. I would suggest using the tools you know, in addition to maybe one or two that you do not. Try using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC together, but don't worry about the Repository pattern just yet. It can be difficult to use EF with a Repository, unless you have a lot of experience with either or both.

**ASP.NET MVC Tutorials** with Entity Framework:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

(notice how they use models directly in the view, sometimes)